# Ng serve for angular application is not starting the server

Tags: node.js, angular

We are using node server to start our angular application using npm run. Due to strange reasons application is taking lot of time to render on browser whenever there is a change and angular build runs.

If there are no changes/ no angular build is run, if we reload the page it loads fast.

We are suspecting the issue is with node and want to run the angular application standalone using ng serve. But running this command is just building but not starting the server.

Need guidance on how we can keep node and run the angular application fast on browser. If not, please suggest where to look if  I had to fix ng serve command to start the angular server as standalone

Comment: What is your angular version? Update package.json to the question as well

Comment: Ng serve only builds means check package.json , tsconfg.json , angular.json etc config files . Check Ng serve cmd log as well.